# Undo DeleteOnClose on FileStream

Tags: c#

I'm having a class that is using a FileStream internally using the FileOption: DeleteOnClose. The normal behavior is when I allocate the class with a filename, I do not use the DeleteOnClose, otherwise I use it.

The only problem is that I happens sometimes that I need to undo the DeleteOnClose.

I would be too lengthy to explain the deeper details here. Of course I could create a copy and copy the contents of the FileStream that have been opened with DeleteOnClose to another FileStream but the file size is too large (>= 30GB) so that this approach is impractical.

Deleting the file manually does not work, since the classes are more or less used as memory containers that need to be handled by the GC. Also when something happens it's not helpful to have dead files lying around.

So I was hoping if there is a way to undo the DeleteOnClose attribute as this can be done, e.g. with SetFileAttributes where e.g. the Temporary flag can be set/unset.

With the comments of TheGeneral and TonPlooij I created a small example to test FileDispositionInfo, but somehow this also doesn't work (copied from http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Roslyn.Test.Utilities/TempFiles/DisposableFile.cs,4d5c94058d1b4cd3):

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        private static extern void SetFileInformationByHandle(SafeFileHandle handle, int fileInformationClass, ref uint fileDispositionInfoDeleteFile, int bufferSize);

        private const int FileDispositionInfo = 4;

        internal static void PrepareDeleteOnCloseStreamForDisposal(FileStream stream)
        {
            // tomat: Set disposition to "delete" on the stream, so to avoid ForeFront EndPoint
            // Protection driver scanning the file. Note that after calling this on a file that's open with DeleteOnClose, 
            // the file can't be opened again, not even by the same process.
            uint trueValue = 1;
            SetFileInformationByHandle(stream.SafeFileHandle, FileDispositionInfo, ref trueValue, sizeof(uint));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Marks given file for automatic deletion when all its handles are closed.
        /// Note that after doing this the file can't be opened again, not even by the same process.
        /// </summary>
        internal static void DeleteFileOnClose(string fullPath)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create,  FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Delete| FileShare.ReadWrite, 8))
            {
                PrepareDeleteOnCloseStreamForDisposal(stream);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
            DeleteFileOnClose("D:\\test.dat");

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best alternative I came up with was to create a hard-link to the temporary file if I want to persist it. DeleteOnClose apparently does not seem to actually delete the file, but only the link to the file, which means if we create another hard link to it before closing the file stream it will be persisted (with a new name).

This of course requires a file system that supports hard links, and I'm not sure if this will work on MacOS/Linux, but on Windows NTFS it seems to work as advertised.

So something like the following appears to work, if it is acceptable to use a temporary file name until we decide to persist it:

```cs
public class TemporaryFile : FileStream
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateHardLink(string lpFileName, string lpExistingFileName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

    public TemporaryFile(string path, FileMode fileMode = FileMode.Create, FileAccess fileAccess = FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare fileShare = FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete, int bufferSize = 4096, FileOptions options = FileOptions.None)
        : base(path, fileMode, fileAccess, fileShare, bufferSize, GetFileOptions(options))
    {                       
    }

    public void PersistTo(string path)
    {
        if (!CreateHardLink(path, Name, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
        }
    }

    private static FileOptions GetFileOptions(FileOptions options)
    {
        return options | FileOptions.DeleteOnClose;
    }
}
```

Which could then be used like:

```cs
using var tempFile = new TemporaryFile(@"c:\tempFile.tmp");
// Write data to TempFile

if (shouldFileBePersisted)
   tempFile.PersistTo(@"c:\permanentFileName.txt");
```

It isn't a perfect solution, but this worked for my purposes, so thought I'd share it.

Comment: Thanks for getting back this this. This is a nice idea. IN the meantime I have found other ways of doing what I want, nevertheless I accepted your approach as an answer,

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you weren't still struggling with the same problem four years later. :D  Just encountered the same question myself and found this solution so thought I might as well share it here. :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer you question directly, no you cant change the option mid way through. The file stream uses the winapi flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`, this cant be changed mid way through, its essentially associated with the file handle, when the handle is closed the operating system cleans up the file, that is it and no work around.

If you want different behavior you will have to implement it yourself after the fact. ie deleting the file after its closed or not.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I already knew the answer. Do you know about the SetFileInformationByHandle and the FileDispositionInfo? I'm currently experimenting, but don't know the answer yet.

Comment: @msedi i thougth you were on to something there for a second, i also double checked the source, for filestream, im not sure there is anything there that will help though. the only thing i can think of (and its one time only) is start the other way around, reopen it if you need to delete on close

Comment: @msedi, open without the DeleteOnClose option. Once you're sure it must be deleted on close, use SetFileInformationByHandle with class FileDispositionInfo  and FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO.DeleteFile to true.

Comment: @TonPlooij yeah it can be set but cant be unset is what im reading. but also yeah use SetFileInformationByHandle, it will save reopening it i guess

Comment: @TonPlooij: I have currently tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Posting the code above to check.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check the return value of `SetFileInformationByHandle`. I think it was most likely failing with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` because you didn't open the file with the `DELETE` access right (not to be confused with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`).

It looks like there is no way to request `DELETE` access when creating a `FileStream`, so you may have to call `CreateFile` yourself and then pass the handle to `FileStream`.